# Can I hide all import declaration into separate file?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a big TypeScript module file with lots of imports. Can I hide some of that imports into separate .ts file that would contain only import declarations?

So I have now something like that

```
import { Test1 } from './test/test/test.component';
import { Test2 } from './test1/test1/test1.component';
import { Test3 } from './test2/test2/test2.component';
import { Test4 } from './test/test3/test3.component';
...
```

So I'd like to have something like that

```
import * from './allDeclarationsFile'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, declare your `allDeclarationsFile.ts` like this:

```
export * from './test/test/test.component';
export * from './test1/test1/test1.component';
export * from './test2/test2/test2.component';
export * from './test/test3/test3.component';
```

or

```
export {Test1} from './test/test/test.component';
//...
```

or if you want to rename something:

```
import * as TC from './test/test/test.component';
export {TC as SomethingElse};
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you can and it's easier than you probably would expect but the caveat is that you will have to access them via a shared namespace object if you want to import them all at once.

**test/index**

```
export { Test1 } from './test/test/test.component';
export { Test2 } from './test1/test1/test1.component';
export { Test3 } from './test2/test2/test2.component';
export { Test4 } from './test/test3/test3.component';
```

This is known as the re-export pattern.

You can now import them as

```
import * as tests from './test/index';
```

Or selectively as

```
import { Test1, Test2 } from './test/index';
```